# How to use factory.LazyAttribute with Faker() functions

Tags: python, django, faker, factory-boy

I am using `factory_boy` to build some fixtures in Django.

I want to use [`factory.LazyAttribute`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html?highlight=lazy#factory.LazyAttribute) to build one attribute based on the condition of another attribute.

```
class MyFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    title = 'My Title' if random() < 0.5 else None
    description = factory.LazyAttribute(
        lambda a: factory.Faker(
            'paragraph', nb_sentences=1, variable_nb_sentences=False
        ) if a.title else None)
```

However, this returns a `string` being `<factory.faker.Faker object at 0x000001B10597BB20>` rather than executing the correct paragraph generation.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`factory.Faker` is a special object: when a factory instantiates an object, it will ask the `factory.Faker` proxy to get a random value from faker.

The simplest way to achieve what you're looking for is to use [`factory.Maybe`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#factory.Maybe):

```py
class MyFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    title = factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoice(["My Title", None])
    description = factory.Maybe('title', factory.Faker('paragraph'))
```

Note that, in the code you shared, the `title = "My title" if random() < 0.5 else None` is computed exactly once, when Python parses the file. I've used [`factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoice`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fuzzy.html#fuzzychoice) to have that random computation performed for each object. This function also uses [factory_boy's randomness management features](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#randomness-management).

Another option would be to use [parameters (`class Params`)](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#parameters):

```py
class MyFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    class Params:
        # Items here will be available to further declarations, but won't be
        # passed to the model constructor.
        description_contents = factory.Faker('paragraph')

    title = factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoice(["My Title", None])
    description = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda a: a.description_contents if a.title else None)
```

Comment: Thanks, given `factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoice` is depreciated, how would you implement this with `Faker` so that it is called on each object?

Comment: You can also use `factory.Faker('random_choice', elements=["My Title", None])`. And I'll have to look into this `FuzzyChoice` deprecation, it has features that `Faker` doesn't…

Comment: How does that work since `description` is a class member variable. When we modify the value of a class variable, we change the value across *all* of the instances at the same time, right? Thanks

Comment: In other words, if I call `MyFactory` to create two instances, will the two instances have the same value for the class member variable `description`?

Answer (score 5):

Or if you need a more specific interaction with the Faker library:

```
from faker import Faker as RealFaker
real_faker = RealFaker()
```

Inside the factory:

```
factory.LazyAttribute(lambda a: real_faker.email())
```